# nginx 405 - uploading img from ember to rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, ember.js, docker, imagemagick

I implemented an image upload in Ember, with dropzone addon (ember-cli-dropzonejs) . 
Rails 5 is running on the server (Ubuntu 14.x), imagemagick is installed in the Rails Docker Container and all files should go to the folder "uploads". 
Everything is running as docker containers, so rails, frontend, database and nginx (1.11.4) are seperate containers.
Now, if I try to upload an image, the server response is a 405 and rails didn't get anything (nothing in the log).

ember hbs file

```
{{drop-zone url=uploadURL
            method='PATCH'
            headers=authentication acceptedFiles='.jpg, .jpeg, .gif, .png'
            resize=''
            maxFilesize='10'
            dictDefaultMessage='Upload file'
            success=(action 'succesfulFileUpload')
            complete=resetUploader
            previewTemplate='<div></div>'
            uploadprogress=progressManipulation
            sending=sending
            }}
```

rails uploader.rb

```
class AvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  version :thumb do
    process resize_to_fill: [200, 200]
  end

  # Add a white list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
  # For images you might use something like this:
  def extension_whitelist
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end

  # Override the filename of the uploaded files:
  # Avoid using model.id or version_name here, see uploader/store.rb for details.
  def filename
    return unless original_filename
    contenttype = original_filename.split('.').last
    "avatar.#{contenttype}"
  end
end
```

nginx config

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl;

  server_name example.com;

    ....
    ssl stuff
    .... 

  location / {
    proxy_read_timeout 150;
    proxy_set_header        Host $host:$server_port;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_pass http://backend:3000;
  }

}
```

Request: [Request img details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecghL.png)

Response: [Response img output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lftHq.png)

If i put the following line into the neginx config (like recommended 100 times on stackoverflow)...

```
error_page  405     =200 $uri;
```

... the server throws the error:

```
Can not read property 'attributes' of undefined
```

This error message is from dropzone. It can't complete the upload. In rails there is nothing received, no entry in logs, nothing...

**UPDATE & SOLUTION**
Finaly i fixed it. The problem was the wrong uploadURL in Handlebars. Local it worked with this wrong url because it was an relative path. But in production an abolute path was needed.

Comment: Too much about containers, nothing about frontend. It would be great if you include some brief info about addon or code you use to upload file from ember to server. Did you check if your frontend sends file? Maybe it doesn't. You should use Dev Tools (Ctrl+Shift+I in Chrome), "Network" tab for that.

Comment: 405 is "method not supported". Something is most probably wrong on sending end. Also you should avoid tricks like `error_page  405     =200 $uri;`. It's just telling web-server "if 405 error happened, change status to 200 and proceed". That's wrong thing to do in real project.

Comment: Just noticed "Request details" link. You use PATCH method, which is most probably is not supported by nginx. You should find a way to change method to POST (in youe ember app). Can't give more detaled answer, because I don't know what do you use to upload. If it's [this](https://github.com/FutoRicky/ember-cli-dropzonejs) dropzone, adding method="post" parameter to component should help

Comment: ember-cli-dropzonejs is the addon I use. 

I use PATCH, beacuse I use the fileupload to add a avatar to the user. so the PATCH goes to the /users/:id path in the users controller. Is that the wrong way? Do I have to add an extra endpoint just for uploading files and add the path from this upload in an extra step to the users model?

Comment: I also put the CORS options to the nginx config like this:

   location / {
        # add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' *;
 if ($cors = "true") {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin";
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, OPTIONS, POST, DELETE, PUT, PATCH';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'User-Agent,Keep-Alive,Content-Type';
        }
 ...
   }

But this is still not the soluten of the problem.

Comment: I see adding an extra endpoint as a solution. Or you can play with nginx config, trying to allow PATCH. I googled on this topic and find out that it should work, but in some circumstances doesn't. Reasons and and solutions are different for everyone though. For someone it's OS, for other it's some nginx module, for someone it's `index` or `try_files` directive. Google 'nginx+patch+method' for details.

Comment: @Tobi you can write your solution as an answer and accept it. that would be helpful to others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly i fixed it. The problem was the wrong uploadURL in Handlebars. Local it worked with this wrong url because it was an relative path. But in production an abolute path was needed.